# Serving static web resources in Spring Boot & Spring Security application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to develop Spring Boot web application and securing it using Spring security java configuration.

After placing my static web resources in '**src/main/resources/public**' as advised [here in Spring blog](http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot), I am able to get the static resources. i.e hitting **`https://localhost/test.html`** in browser do serves the html content.

### Problem

After I enabled Spring Security, hitting the static resource URL requires authentication.

My relevent  Spring Security Java config looks like this:-

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.
            authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/public/**", "/resources/**","/resources/public/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/google_oauth2_login").anonymous()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .logout()
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                        .logoutUrl("/logout") // POST only
                .and()
                    .requiresChannel()
                    .anyRequest().requiresSecure()
                .and()
                    .addFilterAfter(oAuth2ClientContextFilter(),ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
                    .addFilterAfter(googleOAuth2Filter(),OAuth2ClientContextFilter.class)
                .userDetailsService(userService);
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

How should I configure **antMatchers** to permit static resources placed inside src/main/resources/public ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164014/how-to-enable-http-response-caching-in-spring-boot/24179151#24179151

Comment: Note that somewhere down the line you may need to [add content security headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780327/how-to-add-response-header-when-reaching-static-content-using-spring-boot/70024617#70024617) to your static content (including any default/custom error pages) to prevent clickjacking etc exploits

Answer (score 123, accepted):

There are a couple of things to be aware of:

- The Ant matchers match against the request path and not the path of the resource on the filesystem.
- Resources placed in `src/main/resources/public` will be served from the root of your application.
  For example `src/main/resources/public/hello.jpg` would be served from `http://localhost:8080/hello.jpg`

This is why your current matcher configuration hasn't permitted access to the static resources. For `/resources/**` to work, you would have to place the resources in `src/main/resources/public/resources` and access them at `http://localhost:8080/resources/your-resource`.

As you're using Spring Boot, you may want to consider using its defaults rather than adding extra configuration. Spring Boot will, by default, permit access to `/css/**`, `/js/**`, `/images/**`, and `/**/favicon.ico`. You could, for example, have a file named `src/main/resources/public/images/hello.jpg` and, without adding any extra configuration, it would be accessible at `http://localhost:8080/images/hello.jpg` without having to log in. You can see this in action in the [web method security smoke test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/df58a5b5576494d5968019a71b20619e3777da63/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-web-method-security) where access is permitted to the Bootstrap CSS file without any special configuration.

Comment: - I've cloned the spring boot sample repo and run the example ( web method security sample). It is not working. http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.min.css is redirected to login page.
- It is different implemented as described solution. Static file has path: src/main/resources/static/css/

Comment: See the answer of Thomas Lang if you are using Spring Boot 2

Comment: static or css js should be inside src/main/resources/public 
here public folder is the key. 
Thanks

Comment: i think this is needed http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()

Comment: I used `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");` in order to gain access to static resources, but now spring security keeps redirecting me to css and display a 404 page after login, not to the home page. The home page is displayed only after a refresh. I am not using spring boot, but only spring MVC and spring security with the @EnableWebSecurity annotation to activate it.

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson can you please re-upload linked `web method security sample` that you've mentioned in your answer? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 37):

```
  @Override
      public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
          .ignoring()
             .antMatchers("/resources/**"); // #3
      }
```

Ignore any request that starts with "/resources/". This is similar to configuring http@security=none when using the XML namespace configuration.

Comment: Does not work for me, either. While I'm loading my static html from an API, and refer to one of my static files at /resources/css/main.css. The html page rendered by Rest API works fine. However, static css does not.

Answer (score 34):

This may be an answer (for spring boot 2) and a question at the same time.
It seems that in spring boot 2 combined with spring security everything (means every route/antmatcher) is protected by default if you use an individual security mechanism extended from

```
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

If you don´t use an individual security mechanism, everything is as it was?

In older spring boot versions (1.5 and below) as Andy Wilkinson states in his above answer places like `public/** or static/**` are permitted by default.

So to sum this question/answer up - if you are using spring boot 2 with spring security and have an individual security mechanism you have to exclusivley permit access to static contents placed on any route. Like so:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final ThdAuthenticationProvider thdAuthenticationProvider;

private final ThdAuthenticationDetails thdAuthenticationDetails;

/**
 * Overloaded constructor.
 * Builds up the needed dependencies.
 *
 * @param thdAuthenticationProvider a given authentication provider
 * @param thdAuthenticationDetails  given authentication details
 */
@Autowired
public SpringSecurityConfiguration(@NonNull ThdAuthenticationProvider thdAuthenticationProvider,
                                   @NonNull ThdAuthenticationDetails thdAuthenticationDetails) {
    this.thdAuthenticationProvider = thdAuthenticationProvider;
    this.thdAuthenticationDetails = thdAuthenticationDetails;
}

/**
 * Creates the AuthenticationManager with the given values.
 *
 * @param auth the AuthenticationManagerBuilder
 */
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {

    auth.authenticationProvider(thdAuthenticationProvider);
}

/**
 * Configures the http Security.
 *
 * @param http HttpSecurity
 * @throws Exception a given exception
 */
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(Role.Role_Engineer.getValue(),
            Role.Role_Admin.getValue())
            .antMatchers("/settings/**").hasAnyAuthority(Role.Role_Engineer.getValue(),
            Role.Role_Admin.getValue())

            .anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .authenticationDetailsSource(thdAuthenticationDetails)
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/bundle/index", true)
            .failureUrl("/denied")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler());
}
```

}

Please mind this line of code, which is new:

```
.requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
```

If you use spring boot 1.5 and below you don´t need to permit these locations (static/public/webjars etc.) explicitly.

Here is the official note, what has changed in the new security framework as to old versions of itself:

[Security changes in Spring Boot 2.0 M4](https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/15/security-changes-in-spring-boot-2-0-m4)

I hope this helps someone.
Thank you!
Have a nice day!

Comment: I can confirm that adding the extra line fixed it for me (Spring Boot 2.0.3)

Comment: Extra line does help a lot but I need to add few more lines to make it working. Boot version 2.0.6.  (1) .antMatchers("/", "/callback", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**", "/static/**").permitAll() and (2) registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/"); under WebMvcConfigurer.addResourceHandlers().

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @Thomas, I wish this could work for me as well, but unfortunately this is not working (Spring boot 2.7). I have tried many ways like antMatchers and placing to public directory and also the method suggested by you. 
 
 I am able to access other urls, the custom login page without css. Basically none of my static content is accessible after adding custom locin page. 
Could there be something I am missing or anything else to do in Sping boot 2.7

Answer (score 27):

### Here is the ultimate solution, after 20+ hours of research.

**Step 1.** Add 'MvcConfig.java' to your project.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

**Step 2.** Add `configure(WebSecurity web)` override to your SecurityConfig class

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }
```

**Step 3.** Place all static resources in *webapp/resources/..*

Comment: Could you explain what are you doing and why?  "Step1": add static resource handling.  "Step2": remove static resource handling.

Comment: If someone uses XML configuration then in **step 1** you can use this line `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` instead of creating new Java config class.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using webjars. You need to add this in your `configure` method:
`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll();`

Make sure this is the first statement. For example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
         http.formLogin()
         .loginPage("/login")
         .failureUrl("/login?error")
         .usernameParameter("email")
         .permitAll()
         .and()
         .logout()
         .logoutUrl("/logout")
         .deleteCookies("remember-me")
         .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
         .permitAll()
         .and()
         .rememberMe();
    }
```

You will also need to have this in order to have webjars enabled:

```
@Configuration
    public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        ...
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  is deprecated, So you can use WebMvcConfigurationSupport

Answer (score 8):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        String[] resources = new String[]{
                "/", "/home","/pictureCheckCode","/include/**",
                "/css/**","/icons/**","/images/**","/js/**","/layer/**"
        };

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(resources).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/404")
                .permitAll();
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will calling `super.configure` not enable Basic Auth?

Answer (score 4):

i had the same issue with my spring boot application, so I thought it will be nice if i will share with you guys my solution. I just simply configure the **antMatchers** to be suited to specific type of filles. In my case that was only **js filles and js.map**. Here is a code:

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/home", 
       "/login","/favicon.ico","/*.js","/*.js.map").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
   }
  }
```

What is interesting. I find out that **resources path** like ***"resources/myStyle.css"*** in antMatcher didnt work for me at all. If you will have folder inside your resoruces folder just add it in antMatcher like **"/myFolder/myFille.js"*** and it should work just fine.

Comment: For the ones wanting most resources: http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/index.html", "/favicon.ico", "/**/*.js", "/**/*.js.map", "/**/*.css", "/assets/images/*.png", "/assets/images/*.jpg", "/assets/images/*.jpeg", "/assets/images/*.gif", "/**/*.ttf", "/**/*.json", "/**/*.woff", "/**/*.woff2", "/**/*.eot", "/**/*.svg").permitAll() If you're wondering why double ** . With ** it means permit anywhere where there is a file with that extension. Also NOTE the HTTPMETHOD.GET. Replace /assets/images with your own folder. Otherwise just put /*.jpg

Answer (score 4):

In the latest Spring Security 6, the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated.

Declare a `WebSecurityCustomizer` bean instead.

```java
 @Bean
 public WebSecurityCustomizer ignoringCustomizer() {
     return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("...");
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It,s work for spring security 6.0.*

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(
                        "/home/**",
                        "/login/**",
                        "/account/starter/**",
                        "/register/**",
                        "/plugins/**",
                        "/dist/**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/**/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        return http.build();
    }
```

```java
 
                        "/plugins/**",
                        "/dist/**",
                        "/js/**",
```

... they are located in resources/

**plugins, dist, js** - these are the names of directories with resources

Answer (score 1):

Another Spring Security 6 example, which follows the documentation's suggestion "[Favor permitAll over ignoring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html#favor-permitall)" and uses [PathRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.x/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/PathRequest.html) to create static resources request matcher:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .securityMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry ->
                                authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
                                        .requestMatchers(
                                                PathRequest
                                                        .toStaticResources()
                                                        .atCommonLocations())
                                        .permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers("/**")
                                        .fullyAuthenticated()
                )
                
                ...
                
                ;

        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: I have code almost same as this.   But it does not work.   Mine is .....requestMatchers(
"/css/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().   When i access http://localhost:8080/css/myCss.css, i get "No Mapping for GET /css/myCss.css"

Comment: myCss.css is located under resources/static/css/myCss.css

Comment: @NickWills "No Mapping for GET..." errors are not related to the Spring Security config.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution in Spring Boot 3+, Spring Security 6+, and JWT

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    JWTTokenValidatorFilter jwtTokenValidatorFilter = new JWTTokenValidatorFilter();
    jwtTokenValidatorFilter.setSecret(jwtSecret);

    http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(
                    request -> request
                            .requestMatchers("/static/**", "/actuator/**", "/api/v1/auth/**")
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().permitAll())
            .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
            .exceptionHandling(
                    (exceptionHandling) -> exceptionHandling
                            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                    .accessDeniedPage("/error")
            )
            .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenValidatorFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}
```