# Restrict access to Swagger UI

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have swagger UI working with spring-boot. I have a stateless authentication setup for my spring rest api which is restricted based on roles for every api path.

However, I am not sure how can i put `<server_url>/swagger-ui.html` behind Basic authentication.

**UPDATE**

I have following websecurity configured via `WebSecurityConfig`

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/sysadmin/**").hasRole("SYSADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/siteadmin/**").hasRole("SITEADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();

    // Custom JWT based security filter
    httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

Comment: Normally it is worthwhile including how you currently have your security defined so that people can offer solutions that work for your setup. There are a number of ways to do it but knowing more about your imlementation would help.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion without knowing more about your configuration is from this SO question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24920752/1499549

With your updated question details here is an example of what you can add:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/sysadmin/**").hasRole("SYSADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/siteadmin/**").hasRole("SITEADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
            // add the specific swagger page to the security
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();

    // Custom JWT based security filter
    httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

The problem with this is it only protects the Swagger UI page and not the API specification which is loaded as a `.json` file from that UI page.

A better approach is to put the swagger files under a path so that you can just add `antMatchers("/swagger/**").hasRole("USER")`

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to answer. I carried out a small POC to execute the same. I am using Keycloak and Spring Security. Below is my configuration

```
http
                .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**","/swagger-ui.html**","/swagger-ui/").hasRole("admin")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl())
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(authenticationEntryPoint(), new CustomRequestMatcher(AUTH_LIST))
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler());
```

I have a working example [here](https://github.com/chaitanyagprasad/swagger-keycloak-poc)