# Load CSS an JS files with spring boot security

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

What i know is that when using spring security with spring boot, the css and js file are loaded automatically from static/css and static/js folders respectively.
In my case i am using a "ready to use" angular js template for front end in which the js file are not placed in a /js folder (download and see [SB ADMIN ANGULAR](http://startangular.com/product/sb-admin-angular-theme/)) which means that i will have to modify the template's composition sothat it contains /js and /css folders that hold the .css and .js files
[image]

Is there any way to avoid that modification ?
Is it possible to configure Spring boot in a way it becomes able to load .js and .css ?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two aspects here: one is the ability of Spring Boot to serve static resources from a certain, custom location of your choice -- for that you can find and answer [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot).

The second aspect is being able to pass said resources through the Spring Security filter -- for that, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916894/serving-static-web-resources-in-spring-boot-spring-security-application) discussion, the relevant code being:

```
.antMatchers("/","/public/**", "/resources/**","/resources/public/**")
                .permitAll()
```