# How to add headers to requests ignored by Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

My configuration of Spring Security is

```
@Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
      .ignoring()
         .antMatchers("/resources/**"); // #3
  }
```

[Taken from here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24917938/600169)
The documentation for ignorig says

> Allows adding RequestMatcher instances that should that Spring Security should ignore. ... Typically the requests that are registered should be that of only static resources.

I would like to add some headers to files served from resources. 
E.g.: `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000`, `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`.

How I can do it?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I'm having the same issue and would like to leverage Spring Security rather than crafting a homemade servlet filter.

Comment: I did, but my solution got downvote without explanation. So I deleted it. Looking forward for you approach.

Comment: Would you mind sharing it again please? Were you leveraging Spring Security or you ended up creating a servlet filter?

Comment: Undeleted my answer.

Comment: What is your solution? No Upvotes nor accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One solution it to change it to

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
       .and()
       .antMatcher("/resources/**").headers().cacheControl()
}
```

Example how to allow cache control headers PLUS ALL DEFAULT SPRING SECURITY HEADERS.

Comment: Is there other way? Filters?

Comment: There is no ".authorizeRequests()" Method in my WebSecurity class. I'm using Spring 1.2.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This does not "solve" my problem, because the "WebSecurity.ignored()" disables the whole "try to authenticate" thing. And you solution does not. I have posted how I have done it. ;)

Comment: Can you explain what was meant by "WebSecurity.ignored()"?

Comment: The `WebSecurity.ignored()` was meant to be the `web.ignoring()` of you original answer, sorry for the typo.This statement does, as far as I know, disable the whole `HttpSecurity` configuration, but I have found out a trick to run a filter anyway. Like I described it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with the same problem. When I ignore specific requests in WebSecurity, the headers were gone.

I fixed the missing headers, by applying a filter on each request that adds my headers.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .addFilterBefore(securityHeaderFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        ...
}
```

The filter code looks like this. **The important thing to note here, is that the Filter must be declared as a `@Component`.** When you miss the `@Component` annotation, the filter will be ignored.

```
@Component
public class SecurityHeaderFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpServletResponse.setHeader(
                "custom-header1", "header-value1");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader(
                "custom-header2", "header-value2");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following solution:

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean setHeaders() {
        HstsHeaderWriter hstsHeaderWriter = new HstsHeaderWriter(31536000, true);
        XContentTypeOptionsHeaderWriter xContentTypeOptionsHeaderWriter = new XContentTypeOptionsHeaderWriter();
        List<HeaderWriter> headerWriters = new ArrayList<>();
        headerWriters.add(hstsHeaderWriter);
        headerWriters.add(xContentTypeOptionsHeaderWriter);
        HeaderWriterFilter headerWriterFilter = new HeaderWriterFilter(headerWriters);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(headerWriterFilter);
        bean.setOrder(1);
        return bean;
    }
```

The above bean will add a filter globally on all the resources(even the ignoring ones). You can checkout the various implementations of org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriter.java for the different kinds of security headers and add them all to HeaderWriterFilter.java.