# Not detecting login page spring boot

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

### TL;DR

The problem is, if I do something like `http://localhost:8080/registerUser` and then I go to `http://localhost:8080/login` and then I log in, it redirects to `http://localhost:8080/style.css`, but I have put that the `.defaultSuccessUrl("home.html")` and it works if I go to login on the first call.
Seems like `Spring` tries to load the css and it does not have permision or something and then when I log in it tries to, and then the css works....

I have a problem with load css on my `Spring` project, I have it on :

```
resources/static/styles.css
```

and if I don't add this line of code :

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**").anyRequest();
    }
```

the `anyRequest()` did the trick, but now I can call the login page as I was doing before

```
http://localhost:8080/login
```

This login is the defualt form from `Spring`, if I remove the `.anyRequest()` it shows the `login` but doesn't load the css.

My full class is as follows :

```
public class BaseSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //Configure Spring security's filter chain
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**").anyRequest();
    }

    //Configure how requests are secured by interceptors
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                // order matters. First the most specific, last anyRequest()
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers("/registerUser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin() //a login form is showed when no authenticated request
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home.html")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .tokenValiditySeconds(2419200)
                .key("auctions")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/bye.html");
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable();
    }
}
```

What I'm missing?

### EDIT

On my `.html` I do this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{../style.css}"/>
    <title>pewLas</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: How do you load your css ? What url ?

Comment: If you are using spring boot please take a look to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916894/serving-static-web-resources-in-spring-boot-spring-security-application) .

Comment: @atrunov I saw this post, but where do I create the css folder? which root?

Comment: Check what this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{../style.css}"/> evaluates to. I guess that something like web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**/*.css") will do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean with `Check what this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{../style.css}"/> evaluates to` ?

Comment: I saw your edit. When you open the login page from the browser what is the href attribute of the stylesheet ? Your ant matcher is wrong, but I don't know the directory structure to help you.

Comment: What is the url for accessing the css file with anyRequest() enabled ? E.g. http://localhost:8080/css/style.css, or something else ?

Comment: localhost:8080/style.css

Answer (score 0):

Regarding yours question

> I saw this post, but where do I create the css folder? which root?

Please try "/resources/static/css/styles.css"

Comment: and what about html? still the same?

Comment: try "@{../css/style.css}"