# Cannot access content from static folder with Spring Security configurations

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to access content from "src\main\resources\static" folder but i got 401 errors in inspect window in chrome.

Inside of "static" folder i have sub folder called "assets" and the structure bit like this.

`assets/css/**`
`assets/js/**`
`assets/fonts/**`
`assets/image/**`
`assets/css/boostrap/**`

this is my `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class

```
@Configuration
public class OAuthWebFormConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");

registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access").setViewName("authorize");
}

@Configuration
@Order(-20)
protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")//,"/resources/**", "/assets/**"
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(customAuthenticationManager);
    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serving static web resources in Spring Boot & Spring Security application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916894/serving-static-web-resources-in-spring-boot-spring-security-application)

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24920752/592355

Comment: And what url do you hit to access them??

Comment: @KarthikR , Im trying to access customized login page of my Auth-Server. it can be access at "server:port/app/login"

Comment: you have to hit URL like this : `http://<SERVER>:<PORT>/app/assets/image/sunrise.jpg` since `static/**` is added by default in spring boot

Comment: @KarthikR i tried the direct url and didn't work. its showing `Full authentication is required to access this resource`

Comment: Did you add any custom `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` ? If so can you remove and try ?

Comment: I cant remove custom `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` because i need to `map` login and `authorize` views with controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following:

```
.antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
```

So in this way you are allowing all  request for any request thst match /assets/** ( so all the possibilities that you need)

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this before and didn't work for me. still chrome inspect showing `Refused to apply style from 'http://server:port/app/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Comment: This is another problem, set the type to CSS on the declaration of the bootstrap file ... read the error: because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. set like this:type="text/css"

Comment: Also i tried to access resource from direct url and didn't work. its showing `Full authentication is required to access this resource`

Comment: .. and if you dont change your current LoginConfig.class you won't  never access to /assetts