# folder mapping in spring boot to open images from url spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to map local folder to localhost:8080 How can I achieve this.
I am using spring boot. have given permitall to public/pic folder.

how to open in browser like below.

http://localhost:8080/public/pic/default.jpg

above link gives 401 and asks for username and password.

using below code for security in spring

```
@Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public/pic/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
                .logout();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

where should be the folder /public/pic in local system?

Comment: found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916894/serving-static-web-resources-in-spring-boot-spring-security-application?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your config

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/public/pic/**");
}
```

Comment: still its same gives 404.

Comment: 404 is something different. It passes auth step but cannot find your resource