# Mapping resources in Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using `Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE` for serving a web and want to allow the static contents of my page such as `css` for every user, also for unauthenticated ones.

[image]

As I understand, resources under `static` folder are mapped into the root so accessing `localhost:8080/css/sobre.css` I should access my css file. But instead I get redirected to the login page.

This is ok, I know that with Spring Boot 1.5, resources under static were permited by default, but that [changed](https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/15/security-changes-in-spring-boot-2-0-m4).

So, I am using a custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to permit that paths, so it looks like:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
    }
```

But when I go to the page which has a link to the resource i get:

```
No mapping for GET /css/sobre.css
```

[image]

And defenetly mapping every resource into the actual file is not the right approach.

So I don't really know how to do this. What am I missing? I just want to:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/sobre.css" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serving static web resources in Spring Boot & Spring Security application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916894/serving-static-web-resources-in-spring-boot-spring-security-application)

Comment: @dur That's URL is another approach to allow the resources, and ir works, but the mapping of the URL fails somehow.

Comment: @dur By default Springs sets that property to /static, /public, /resources and /META-INF/resources and I have it under /static, so, no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do three things:

- Removing `@EnableWebMvc` from the main class.
- Adding a exception to that path in the Security adapter:

  ```
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
      web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**");
  }
  ```

  OR with `HttpSecurity`:

  ```
  .antMatchers("/css/*").permitAll()
  ```
- In case your static folder is not called "static", setting the root path to the resources folder:

  `spring.resource.static-locations= "classpath:/publicfiles/"`