# Static resources not found in Spring MVC app

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, staticresource

I'm working on MVC web app. Using Spring Boot 2.0.1 with Spring Security.
And I get error 404 when try reaching static resources.

[image]

I've tried diefferent things, I've read many topics, but can't find any solution.

Configuretion class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class FriendlyFireChessApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private SpringApplicationContext springApplicationContext;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(FriendlyFireChessApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FriendlyFireChessApplication.class, args);
    }

    /*
    some beans here
    */

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Project strucutre:

[image]

index.html:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Friendly fire chess</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/static/css/style.css'/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="main_header">
                <div>
                    <a id="icon"><img src='/static/img/logo_1.png' width="40" height="70" border="0" /></a>
                </div>

                <div id="main_title">
                    <span>Friendly Fire Chess</span>
                </div>

                <div class="authentication_bar">
                    <div>
                        <span><a id="log_in_button" href='http://www.ffchess.org/login'>Login</a></span>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <span><a id="sign_in_button" href="http://www.ffchess.org/signin">Sign In</a></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </header>

    </html>
```

Security settings:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL)
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, SecurityConstants.VERIFICATION_EMAIL_URL)
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST_URL)
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.PASSWORD_RESET_URL)
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers(SecurityConstants.H2_CONSOLE)
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers(SecurityConstants.HOME_PAGE)
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/css/**", "/static/img/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
            .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

}
```

What's wrong with all of this?

Comment: Did you see this already ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916894/serving-static-web-resources-in-spring-boot-spring-security-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per project structure, all your resources will be copied to `static` directory under your classpath and there won't be any location like `resources`. Hence, it would not be able to resolve.

resource location should be specified along with classpath

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
   .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
```

for safer side, you can class multiple location lookup as well like this

```
.addResourceLocations(new String[]{"classpath:/static/", "/"});
```

Spring includes these by default unless overridden

```
["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
```

Comment: I've already tried specifying  {registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
   .addResourceLocations("/static/");} and bunch of other options in this method. I tried without any ResourceHandler as well. Does't work. I think the issue is somewhere in Security, but can't find it...