# Images in html for Spring thymeleaf won't show up

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

Below, I am using login.html as the page where I am adding the image `test.png` within `/static/images/`

[image: layout]

So, in login.html, I have `<img src="../static/images/test.png" width="1000" th:src="@{images/test.png}"/>`, which gives a blank image. Why isn't it showing up?

In my `SecurityConfiguration.java` file, I have

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      //.antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
      .antMatchers("/static").permitAll()
      .and().formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login")
      .permitAll();
```

When I use this configuration, it uses the default index.html page which shows the image fine. But, If I uncomment `.antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")`, it will bring me to login.html, but I can't view the image.

Comment: looks ok.. (new) resources maybe not picked up...  clean build may fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 problems I can spot.

1. Instead of `.antMatchers("/static")` you should rather have `.antMatchers("/images/**")` since anything from `src/main/resources/static` will be served from the root of your application (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24920752/5684265) - mind that folders "public" and "static" are interchangeable to Spring Boot).
2. Order of matchers for `.authorizeRequests()` matters! Just look as last example of [method's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeRequests--). You should have your ant matchers reversed:

```
   .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll() // more detailed paths should go first
   .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")   // more general paths should go last
```

3. Consider using `th:src="@{/images/test.png}"` instead of `th:src="@{images/test.png}"`. The extra slash at beginning makes the path relative to the root of your application what gets along with first advice. As stated in [Thymeleaf's documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls):

> Relative URLs starting with `/` (eg: `/order/details`) will be automatically prefixed by the application context name.