# Spring boot app containerized with jib not serving static content

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

i have a mixed code container containing:

- a java spring boot app (backend)
- a vue.js app (frontend)

the container is being build using jib - the 'static' content are deployed with a gradle copy job in the /app/resources/static directory.
Here is the Layout:

[image: screenshot of dive]

The backend is secured with spring security.

The frontend is excluded from spring security chain:

[image: bean configuration for frontend]

Starting the container and trying to access the index.html yields in a 401 "Unauthorized":

[image: result from http-get]

I tried different things already (changing the static-path, modifying the security chain, ...) but i always get the same result. I am a bit lost and kindly request guidance :)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the key here is the paths specified in `.requestMatchers(...)` refer to the HTTP request's path, not the path on the filesystem.

You'll notice the request shown from the browser is to `/index.html`, which is not specified in the list of ignored request matchers in the `webSecurityCustomizer` bean. [This answer from Andy Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24920752/540624) goes into more detail.

Modifying the bean to:

```java
@Bean
WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
  return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/index.html", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/actuator/**");
}
```

Should fix things.

You might also want to take Jib out of the equation while you're developing locally and just try running the application with `mvn spring-boot:run` or `./gradlew bootRun`. Then, once things are working, try doing the same with the Jib-built Docker image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That did the trick :) Now, the index.html is being served. I will try to skip the jib-step for development purposes as you suggested.